# How to parse the second child node from xml page in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I am new to iphone development.I want parse an you-tube XML page and retrieve its contents and display in a RSS feed.

my xml page is

```
<entry>
<id>xxxxx</id>
<title>xxx xxxx xxxx</title>
<content>xxxxxxxxxxx</content>
<media:group>
 <media:thumbnail url="http://tiger.jpg"/>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

To retrieve the content  i am using xml parsing.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            

currentElement = [elementName copy];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {

    entry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentcontent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
    [entry setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [entry setObject:currentDate forKey:@"content"];
    [stories addObject:[entry copy]];
    }}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [currentTitle appendString:string];
} else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"content"]) {
    [currentLink appendString:string];
 }
 }
```

I am able to retrieve id , title and content value and display it in a table-view.How can i retrieve tiger image URL and display it in table-view.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            

    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"])
    imageUrl=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
}
```

Since you already have an if statement in this method, use else if for this one

Comment: What data type i should declare the imageUrl

Comment: what  should be given in "parse did end element" and "found characters" method

Comment: imageUrl should be a string, also for getting the attribute value, you need not specify about it in the other methods.

Comment: where did it check for the element<media:group>

Comment: the parser will be checking the tags continuously one after the other, no matter whether they are child nodes or parent nodes, but considers as a string. The values of the attributes will be stored in the attributeDict with the attribute name as the key. Since the attributes are within the tag, they are obtained at didStartElement: method. But value of the tag(here xxxxx for <id>) is obtained at foundCharacters: method.

Comment: But when the tag <media:group> has more than one element with same name, how can I extract a specific element, say the second element: `<media:group>
<media:thumbnail url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xttpcgyKhLE/default.jpg" height="90" width="120" yt:name="default" />
<media:thumbnail url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xttpcgyKhLE/mqdefault.jpg" height="180" width="320" yt:name="mqdefault" />
<media:thumbnail url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xttpcgyKhLE/hqdefault.jpg" height="360" width="480" yt:name="hqdefault" />
<yt:duration seconds="0" />
 </media:group>`